# Why am I getting "Uncaught(in Promise)" error with then?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So I have a chain of `then`:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
      .then(exhibits => this.exhibits = exhibits)
      .then(exhibits => {console.log("0", exhibits[0])})
      .then(exhibits => {console.log("1", exhibits[1])});
  }
```

I get the error `Uncaught (in promise):` at the second `console.log`. I can't figure out why that is? Thank you!

Comment: need to return value in then, function to make it available in next then callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

You have assigned `this.exhibits = exhibits` but have not returned anything. Thus on next `.then()` `exhibits` is not accessible and thus causing the issue. You can return it like:

```
.then(exhibits => {
    this.exhibits = exhibits
    return exhibits
})
```

Though this might not be needed as you not using `this.exhibits` anywhere. So, you can simply return `exhibits` like:

```
.then(exhibits => exhibits)
```

Though this is also unnecessary and you can simply remove it and access `exhibits` array like:

```
this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
  .then(exhibits => {
    if(exhibits && exhibits.length){
      console.log("0", exhibits[0] || {})
      console.log("1", exhibits[1] || {})
    }       
  })
```

Or, if you are using `this.exhibits` elsewhere, then you can use:

```
this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
  .then(exhibits => {
    this.exhibits = exhibits
    return exhibits
  })
  .then(exhibits => {
    if (exhibits && exhibits.length) {
      console.log("0", exhibits[0] || {})
      console.log("1", exhibits[1] || {})
    }
  })
```

---

Also, while making ajax calls always use proper error handling, i.e. a `catch`, which is useful to accomplish new actions even after an ajax call has failed in the chain like:

```
this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
  .then(exhibits => {
    this.exhibits = exhibits
    return exhibits
  })
  .then(exhibits => {
    if (exhibits && exhibits.length) {
      console.log("0", exhibits[0] || {})
      console.log("1", exhibits[1] || {})
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error: " + error);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the first `.then` to the second one, so `exhibits` won't exists in your second `.then` (neither in your third one).

You should return it from the first `.then`, or logging it from `this.exhibits`.

Something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
    .then(exhibits => {
      this.exhibits = exhibits
      return exhibits
    })
    .then(exhibits => {
      console.log("0", exhibits[0])
      return exhibits
    })
    .then(exhibits => {
      console.log("1", exhibits[1])
    });
}
```

or maybe better

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.contentfulService.getExhibits()
    .then(exhibits => this.exhibits = exhibits)
    .then(exhibits => console.log("0", this.exhibits[0]))
    .then(exhibits => console.log("1", this.exhibits[1]));
}
```